# IsolatedStorage and navigation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigation, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I can't sort this weird issue out and I have tried anything and everything I can think of.

I got 5 pages, everyone of them passing variables with navigation this way:

Pass:

```
NavigationSerice.Navigate(new Uri("/myPage.xaml?key=" + myVariable, UriKind.Relative));
```

Retrieve:

```
If (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey(myKey))
{
    String retrievedVariable = NavigationContext.QueryString["myKey"].toString();
}
```

I open a list on many pages and one of the pages automatically deletes an item from the list actualProject (actualProject is a variable for a string list). Then, when I go so far back that I reach a specific page - the app throws an exception. Why? I have no idea.

The code that deletes the item:

```
                // Remove the active subject from the availible subjects
            unlinkedSubjects.Remove(actualSubject);
            unlinkedsubjectsListBox.ItemsSource = null;
            unlinkedsubjectsListBox.ItemsSource = unlinkedSubjects;
```

Then the page that throws the exception's OnNavigatedTo event:

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("key"))
        {
            actualProject = NavigationContext.QueryString["key"];
            try
            {
                //Read subjectList from IsolatedStorage
                subjectList = readSetting(actualProject) != null ? (List<String>)readSetting(actualProject) : new List<String>();

                //Put the subjectList into the subjectListBox
                subjectListBox.ItemsSource = subjectList;

                //Set the subjectsPageTitle to the "actualProject" value, to display the name of the current open project at the top of the screen
                subjectsPageTitle.Text = actualProject;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (language.Equals("en."))
                {
                    // Language is set to english
                    MessageBox.Show("Couldn't open the project, please try again or please report the error to Accelerated Code - details on the about page");
                }
                else if (language.Equals("no."))
                {
                    // Language is set to norwegian
                    MessageBox.Show("Kunne ikke åpne prosjektet, vennligst prøv igjen eller rapporter problemet til Accelerated Code - du finner detaljer på om-siden");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Exception:

- _exception  {System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.}  System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

**My theory:**
The app kind of loads the currently opened and modified List. Is that possible? No idea.

Comment: Can you write on which line it crashes?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your message. Will write it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

So there are a number of ways to pass data between pages.

The way you have chosen is the least suggested.

[You can use the PhoneApplicationService.Current dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) but this is messy also if you have a ton of variables, doesn't persist after app shut down and could be simplified.

I wrote a free DLL that kept this exact scenario in mind called EZ_iso.

[You can find it here](http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2)

Basically what you would do to use it is this.

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class YourPageVars{
   [DataMember]
   public Boolean Value1 = false;

   [DataMember]
   public String Value2 = "And so on";

   [DataMember]
   public List<String> MultipleValues;
}
```

Once you have your class setup you can pass it easily between pages

```
YourPageVars vars = new YourPageVars { /*Set all your values*/ };

//Now we save it

EZ_iso.IsolatedStorageAccess.SaveFile("PageVars",vars);
```

That's it! Now you can navigate and retrieve the file.

```
YourPageVars vars = (YourPageVars)EZ_iso.IsolatedStorageAccess.GetFile("PageVars",typeof(YorPageVars));
```

This is nice because you can use it for more than navigation. You can use it for anything that would require Isolated storage. This data is serialized to the device now so even if the app shuts down it will remain. You can of course always delete the file if you choose as well.

Please make sure to refer to the documentation for any exceptions you have. If you still need help feel free to hit me up on twitter [@Anth0nyRussell](https://twitter.com/Anth0nyRussell) or amr@AnthonyRussell.info

Comment: Very good answer :) - will definitely try it tomorrow, getting a little late here - and work tomorrow :)

Comment: Not to be self serving but it really is a great DLL. There is hardly an app I create that I don't use it. Like I said feel free to ping me if you have questions.

Comment: I'm looking into my issue now, really nice answer - but do you think that's the issue that causes my app to crash? Whenever I remove this code it works: unlinkedSubjects.Remove(actualSubject);

Comment: If the code you posted is what you have in your actual source then I see no reason it would throw that error. It's hard to diagnose because of this. This is why I posted the answer I did. This DLL is much more scalable then the method you are using as well. You could pass 1000 variables just as easily as 1 with this DLL where as 1000 variables with navigation variables would be a nightmare

Comment: That's why it's so difficult - and I kinda have to be certain because it'll take ages to switch all the navigation code in my app to the new dll:) Wonderful code, but switching and result in same error is sooo bad

Comment: That error is from querying the navigation string. The DLL doesnt do that